# Events not adding in Iphone 5 default calendar

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app i have to add the event to Iphone default calendar.I wrote the code as follows

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init]; 
EKEvent *event1  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event1.notes=descriptionStr;
event1.startDate =edate;
event1.endDate=fdate;
[event1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[event1 setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
```

Problem is with Iphone5. For 4S and previous versions event is adding perfectly. please guide me.Thank you.

Comment: Do you check wether you can access the calendar: [`+ (EKAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatusForEntityType:(EKEntityType)entityType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567-CH1-SW47)

Comment: No i didn't check, its working fine for 4s, i have to made the app compatible to ios6. can you explain more in detail @rckoenes

Comment: Read the Apple documentation in the link above, I have not yet used used EventKit in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Apple documentation of EKEventStoreClassRef:

> On iOS 5 and later, initialize an event store object with the default init method. On iOS 6 and later, you must request access to an entity type after the event store is initialized with requestAccessToEntityType:completion: for data to return.

Does it work on 4S with iOS 6 installed?

Comment: Thanq for responding,event is adding for 4S with iOS6, not for Iphone 5. I never dealt with ekevents before,can u explain in detail plz @ lammert

Comment: There is a nice guide from Apple about this topic: [Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765)